# making histogram using stored frequency in python

Tags: python, histogram, frequency

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to make a histogram with frequency vector except
   using plt.bar? I have a frequency vector of size one million and
   bar plot seems to be very slow on that.
2. I tried a bar plot with smaller size data but seems even after setting
       a width size, I am still getting a different wide size for each bar
       as following, any way to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe what you're looking for is called a "step plot", where the height and location of each step is fixed by the input. A histogram by definition uses the actual sample frequency as the height in each interval. To do this, you can use the [`drawstyle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_drawstyle) keyword argument to the [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) function.  The different step styles further control the location of the steps (left/right edge with `drawstyle="steps-pre"` or `"steps-post"`, or midpoint for `"steps-mid"`).
2. I think you're giving the width parameter too small a value (0.05), causing aliasing effect in the resulting (raster?) image.  If the image/screen resolution is low, the non-uniform appearance will be much worse.  Try increase the parameter to a much larger value (say, 0.5) will make the look much more uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I want sth like this [image]

but with one million dimension in x which seems not possible with plt.bar.
With the step you get sth like this[image]

and if I increase the dimension all the details are gone.